# sprintf with __() translate and javascript

Tags: wordpress, printf, translate

i have

```
<label>'. sprintf(__( 'Enter code that sended to %s','adforest' ),'<span id="phone_number"><span>').'</label>
```

that span get from javascript function

it possible(how) or not?

Answer (score 0):

i get my answer.
you can do it but set !

i edit my code

```
<label>'. sprintf(__( 'Enter code that sended to %s','adforest' ),'<span id="phone_number"></span>').'</label>
```

S F My English!